# "Requires Python '>=3.5, <4'" but Python 3 is installed

Tags: python, linux, google-sheets, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4

I want to use the Google Sheets API. For this i need to install a package:
`pip install gspread oauth2client`

If I try this package to install I get this error:
`rsa requires Python '>=3.5, <4' but the running Python is 2.7.16`

```
Python 2.7.16
```

```py
Python 3.9.4
```

Btw:
`pip install  "gspread" "oauth2client"` didnt help

Want can I do to change the running Python to Python 3 ?
Thanks

Comment: In most cases `pip3` or `python3 -m pip` will do the trick. You will also have to run your code with `python3` then.

Comment: If the command `pip3` exists, use that instead of pip. Otherwise use `which -a pip` to see where pip is, and enter the full path for the python3 version.

Comment: Thanks, I needed to update pip first, then it did work.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `pip3 install gspread` instead of only pip.

`pip3` refers to your Python3 version installed, `pip2` to the Python2 version, while `pip` chooses the best one based on the environment in which you're running the command.

Answer (score 0):

I had a strange issue where `python3 -m pip install vosk` wasn't working and gave the error `(requires-python:>=3)` even though I definitely have python 3 installed as /usr/bin/python3.

I "fixed" it with `venv`:

```bash
python3 -m venv /my/dir
. /my/dir/bin/activate
pip install --upgrade pip
pip install vosk
# and it worked!
```

If course I would have liked to do this without `venv`, but *sigh*.

(Now that i think of it i wonder if simply upgrading pip was enough to solve the issue.)

Hope this helps someone else!